# Moving view after view rotated, the touch position in view is wrong

Tags: swift, rotation, swift4, cgaffinetransform, touchmove

I have a target view (blue view and red view is for upper-left position). I am trying to move this view following by a finger. Everything is fine if the view does not rotated.
[image]
But when I rotated the view and move, for the first time is fine. but it is weird from the second time and onwards that the view is bounced out from a finger position.
[image]

I am using concatenating to combine transforms.

```
targetView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: touchPosition.x, y: touchPosition.y).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:radian))
```

I am not familiar with transforms and math is not my good. Does rotation really affect to translate (moving)? or Do I misunderstand something? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the point around which the view will pivot using the `anchorPoint` on `CALayer`.

`view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(0.5, 0.5)`

[You can read more about this property here.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410817-anchorpoint)

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple, you should not apply a transformation, if you want to move an UIView. Instead you need to move the center point of the View.

So what you need to do is save the `center` of the View, when the PanGesture begins and then move the `center` by the translation-Point of the PanGesture. Try something like this:

```
if sender.state == .began {
    panGestureStartLocation = view.center
} else {
    let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
    view.center = CGPoint(x: panGestureStartLocation.x + translation.x, y: panGestureStartLocation.y + translation.y)
}
```